# Testing for macros by name

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I'm curious to know how I would go about testing for macros by name. I need to do something that would be the logical equivalent of the following:

```
\def\doit#1{%
\if#1==\foo I got a foo\fi
\if#1==\bar I got a bar\fi
}
```

Now, of course I'm aware that `\if` doesn't work that way. The notation == isn't actually a thing, and the fact that `\if` expands macros is undesirable for my purposes, because I might want to do `\doit\foo` without `\foo` even being defined. However, I hope that the above pseudo-code serves to illustrate my question nonetheless.

I'm aware that there are better ways to pass named "flags" to a macro than as control sequences, but for reasons I won't go into here I really am constrained to macro names, and I really do need to be able to check if, given two macro tokens, their names are both the same.

Note that I'm using Plain TeX, and I'm seeking a solution that uses only TeX primitives and/or Plain TeX macros.

Comment: Will you always use it the way `\doit\foo` or would you want to also use it `\doit{foo}`?

Comment: Always \doit\foo. Of course that's a contrived example, but in my actual code the project is such that I have \doit\foo, and I need to distinguish between \foo and \bar, even when neither is defined.

Comment: Does Plain TeX know `\pdfstrcmp`?

Comment: @rutski OK, this is a string-like test. Do you need it to be expandable? If so, are there likely to be spaces in the names (under 'edge case' circumstances)?

Comment: @Werner Not a TeX90 or even e-TeX primitive. You can do an expandable string-based test using `\if` and some looping even without it: easier of course if the test does not need to be expandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need an expandable test, here's a possibility. I assume you have a finite set of flags.

```
% set the flags
\begingroup\escapechar=-1
\xdef\fooname{\string\foo}
\xdef\barname{\string\bar}
\endgroup

\def\nameequal#1#2{%
  TT\fi
  \begingroup
  \escapechar=-1
  \edef\nameequaltemp{\string#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifx\nameequaltemp#2}

\def\doit#1{%
  \if\nameequal#1\fooname
    I saw foo%
  \else
    \if\nameequal#1\barname
      I saw bar%
    \else
      I saw rubbish%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\doit\foo

\doit\bar

\doit\foobar

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just `\edef\@tempa{\string#1}\edef\@tempb{\string#2}\ifx\@tempa\@tempb`?

Comment: @JosephWright I like it better to declare the admissible flags beforehand.